# how can I put data in mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL database where I want to push data to, but after running the code and then looking inside the mySQL database, nothing changes.

Code below is for practice purpose, it is not used on a live website.

```
<?php
    $myPDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_information','root', 'root');

$result = $myPDO->query("INSERT INTO user_information (first_name, last_name, type_text)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')");
?>
```

if I use following query directly in mySQL than it works:

```
INSERT INTO user_information (first_name, last_name, type_text)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')
```

but when I do it with php it does not work.

UPDATE:

I have defined dbname in a wrong way. 
It is working now.

Comment: You're not checking for errors, so look in your error logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: You should never login to the database as 'root'. It exposes you to mistakes.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I think you are missing a ";" at the end of the SQL-statement.

Comment: The semi-colon is not necessary here @wfehr

Comment: The `;` after `(first_name, last_name, type_text);` is definitely not needed.

Comment: That would be correct @wfehr

Comment: Closing the question as a typo.

Comment: You should practice with prepared statements. `query()` very rarely should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this and have a sql injection prevention

```
$stmt = $myPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO user_information (first_name,last_name, type_text)" 
        . "VALUES (?,?,?);");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', 'John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->get_result();
```

this will define every input as string and prevent inputing everything to the database but if not you can just remove the semicolon

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax is

```
$result = $myPDO->query("INSERT INTO user_information (first_name, last_name, type_text) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')");
```

Comment: The question was answered in comments and should be closed as a typo.